# JavaScript ReverseMatch

Tags: javascript, regex

Is simple, i have this sentence:

```js
str = "aeiou";
```

Need RegExp to scan string every X chars, but in reverse.

**Example:**

```js
let every=2,
    match = new RegExp(/>>RegExp Here<</gi);  
//result "a ei ou"
```

Comment: I don't understand what is "reversed" here

Comment: Please post the code that fails to see where the programming issue is.

Comment: Why do you need a RegEx here?  There are other tools for string parsing/manipulation other than regexes.

Comment: I speak spanish, used translater.
Need that RegExp because need format numbers, and *more functions*, but i dont wanna use plugins, only simple javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```js
let str = "Hello world, 13th Mar 2020.";
let every=2;
let rx = new RegExp(`(?=(?:[^]{${every}})+$)`, 'g');
console.log(str.replace(rx, "_"));
// => H_el_lo_ w_or_ld_, _13_th_ M_ar_ 2_02_0.
```

The regex is `/(?=(?:[^]{2})+$)/g`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nDk5Be/1/). It matches any location in the string that is followed with one or more repetitions of any two chars up to the string end, and inserts `_` at that location.

**Details**

- `(?=` - start of a positive lookahead:

  - `(?:[^]{2})` - any char (`[^]` = `[\s\S]`), 1 or more times (thanks to `+`)
  - `$` - end of string
- `)` - end of the lookahead.